# SVG clipPath creates strange outline effect around the clipPath area

Tags: html, svg

Creating a white  that fills the entire area within a circular clipPath will have a black border if there's a (completely covered) black element underneath it. Even if I make the circle have 500 radius or sandwich the rectangle between two huge circles, the black will still end up around the clipPath's defined area:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <clipPath id="Clip">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"></circle>
  </clipPath>
  <g clip-path="url(#Clip)">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="black"></rect>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="51" fill="white"></circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I tried using transformZ and translateZ from some other answers but nothing seems to get rid of the black line around the edge. [Here's a jsFiddle to show what I mean](https://jsfiddle.net/frog42/avhfw8r3/14/)

Comment: @RobertLongson Could you show me in the provided jsFiddle where you would apply crispEdges? Because it doesn't seem to address the issue.

Comment: Decided to just switch to mask. Seems it's better-suited to my use.